# How to make Touchable component always touchable in expo

Tags: react-native

is there any trick to ensure all touched ( onPress ) work at 100% width and height ? for example sometimes happens that my View is 100 x 100 and inside is EXPO icon ( font ) let say 24 x 24 and what happens is sometimes touch is not registered, its registered only when i click exactli on Icon ( font ) with pixel precision and no around

tryed

- hitSlop
- pointerEvents
- Pressable (RN)
- TouchableOpacity from react-native-gesture-handler
- TouchableWithoutFeedback
- flexing parent, chieldren ...
- z indexing and elevations

also with Touch inspector i see big HIT BOX but its fake information cuz touch is not that big

but i cant figure out why

example code

```js
<View style={[{flex: 1}]}>
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
                    style={[{flex: 1}]}
                    onPress={() => props.dismiss()}>
                    <Entypo type="Entypo" name="chevron-thin-left" color={themeColor.iconColor} size={22} />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
```

btw funny is that it only appy onPress event when i do onPressIn it works ..., but this event is terrible for most cases

Comment: How are you using hitSlop?

Comment: @MatinZadehDolatabad like this ```hitSlop={{top: 10, bottom: 15, left: 10, right: 10}}```

Comment: Try using `width: '100%'` as style. I am sure that is kinda styling issue.

Comment: @MatinZadehDolatabad i hope so but strange is it doesnt register only on android iPhone is Allright with it :/